# javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: in glassfish server v2

Tags: glassfish, ejb-3.0, netbeans6.8

I'm implementing stateless session bean ejb3 in glassfish server using netbeans. First time, it is working properly. Later, I'm getting the exception as follows:

```
LDR5012: Jndi name conflict found in
[SampleEjb3]. Jndi name
[Lulu.HellostatelessRemote] for bean
[HellostatelessBean] is already in
use. LDR5013: Naming exception while
creating EJB container: 
javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException:
Use rebind to override
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.TransientContext.doBindOrRebind(TransientContext.java:292)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:232)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContextProviderImpl.bind(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:111)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.bind(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:90)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:476)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:404)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.NamingManagerImpl.publishObject(NamingManagerImpl.java:237)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.NamingManagerImpl.publishObject(NamingManagerImpl.java:190)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1015)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:232)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:654)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.loadEjbs(AbstractLoader.java:536)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.doLoad(ApplicationLoader.java:188)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.doLoad(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:126)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.load(AbstractLoader.java:244)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.load(AbstractManager.java:225)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLifecycle.onStartup(ApplicationLifecycle.java:217)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:442)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:120)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:411)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:338)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:412)
```

Then, I'll remove the ejb module from the glassfish server and I'll restart the server. It will work then. So, how to overcome this problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try restart server. Weblogic 11g has this bug.

Comment: Restart helped with GlassFish (v3) too.